# IIF statement giving error

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, if, personalization

I am super new to using AMPScript and have been watching some videos and browsing this forum and have been putting in the exact same IIF statements but I have been getting this error:

The subscriber preview failed to generate. Review the details, correct all issues, and try again.

An error occurred when attempting to resolve a function call. See inner exception for detail.

> Function Call: IIF(EMPTY(Contact First Name), "There", (Contact First Name) Index: 18226 TransCode Type: HTML Content Type: HTML Substitution Level: Subscriber Message Context: Preview

> An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail. Script Expression: EMPTY(Contact First Name) MemberID: 1052936 JobID: 0

> Invalid characters appear at the end of the parameter value Function Call: EMPTY(Contact First Name) Parameter Value: Contact Invalid Character: F

The token works when I just have:

```
Hi %%Contact First Name%%
```

But I am trying to add a fallback so if the Contact First Name field is empty I would like it to say, "Hi," but if the field has a name it should generate, "Hi John,"

Hi `%%=IIF(EMPTY(Contact First Name), ",", (Contact First Name)=%%`,

What is broken with my IIF statement?

Comment: `IF` has a single "I", not two of them...

Comment: I am using an Inline IF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use naked personalization strings!

[AttributeValue()](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue) will return an empty string if the contextual variable doesn't exist -- or in your case, contains a space.

Generally speaking you can surround these personalization strings in square brackets when they contain spaces (e.g. `[Contact First Name]`, but you might as well just use AttributeValue().

```ampscript
%%[

set @ContactFirstName = AttributeValue("Contact First Name")

]%%
<!-- Other HTML --> 
Hi %%=IIF(EMPTY(@ContactFirstName), "there", @ContactFirstName)=%%,
```

Comment: This works thanks for the help!

If I wanted to get rid of "there" and have it display as "Hi," without the space after Hi when there's no name and have a space after "Hi ContactName,". Is there a way to concatenate it?

Answer (score 0):

re: This works thanks for the help! If I wanted to get rid of "there" and have it display as "Hi," without the space after Hi when there's no name and have a space after "Hi ContactName,". Is there a way to concatenate it? –

You should be able to just do this -

%%[

set @ContactFirstName = AttributeValue("Contact First Name")

]%%

Hi %%=IIF(EMPTY(@ContactFirstName), "", concat(" ", @ContactFirstName))=%%,